# How to add multiple roles to a user and check this using FOSUSERBUNDLE in symfony2

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

How to add multiple roles and check this using FOSUSERBUNDLE in symfony2 ?

I have some issues to add multiple roles to a single user FOS.Any idea how to add and check this in my controller and twig ?

Comment: I don't know why negative reviews

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FOSUserBundle has addRole() and removeRole() methods for adding and removing roles.

Action to do that might be like that:

```
     /**
     * @Route("/admin/user/change-role/{id}/{role}")
     */
    public function roleAction($id, $role)
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $user = $em->getRepository('MyGreatBundle:User')->find($id);

        if (!$user) {
            throw $this->createNotFoundException('No user found for id '.$id);
        }

        if ($user->hasRole($role)){
            $user->removeRole($role);
        } else {
            $user->addRole($role);
        }

        $username = $user->getUsername();

        $em->flush();

        return $this->render('MyGreatBundle:Default:role.html.twig', array('result' => $username, 'role' => $role, ));
    }
```

This action add or remove role from user. Action accepts id of user and role. Role can be for example: ROLE_NEWS, ROLE_EVENT, ROLE_SOMETHING ... If user already has this role, then action will remove that role, otherwise it will add.

You can also create similar action for checking role with method hasRole().